# Making web form for updating data in Firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I am making an interface to manipulate data in Firebase. I managed to make a form that inserts new data, I have a list of retrieved data, the only thing that is missing is editing/updating existing data.

I am using Foundation 6 to speed up coding HTML and CSS and I created a modal that pops up when you click on a name. Also, I made that every name has a class that is their child key in Firebase so I can open data for the right item. I've stuck here and I don't know how to make that form in modal to fill data from clicked name. Can somebody help me a bit?

[image]

[image]

Here is my code:

```
      var ref = new Firebase("https://myname.firebaseio.com/data/users");
        ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
          var key = snapshot.key();
          var data = snapshot.val();
          var name = data.name;
          var city = data.city;
          $("#results").append($("<li class=\"" + key + "\">" + "<a data-open=\"modal\">" + name + ", " + city + "</a></li>"));
          // this is for filling up the form with loaded data
          $(".name").val(name); 
          $(".name").focus(function(){
              $(this).val(name);
          });
        });
```

Comment: You need to show relevant code.

Comment: I added code I have for now

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://myname.firebaseio.com/data/users");
var data;
ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  data = snapshot.val();
  $("#results").empty();
  Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
    var value = data[key];
    var name = value.name;
    var city = value.city;
    var li = $("<li class=\"" + key + "\">" + "<a data-open=\"modal\">" + name + ", " + city + "</a></li>");
    $("#results").append(li);
    li.click(function() {
      $('#name').val(name);
      $('#city').val(city);
      $('#key').val(key);
    });
  });
});
$('form').submit(function() {
  var key = $('#key').val();
  var name = $('#name').val();
  var city = $('#city').val();
  data[key].name = name;
  data[key].city = city;
  ref.set(data);
  return false;
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uvr01qtc/)**

Comment: I've made some progress with my code actually. When I click on my user link and modal opens I managed to grab child key so I can concatenate this key in Firebase URL and just grab data I need and then make a function for updating it when I click form update button, this part shouldn't be a problem. I have some silly problem with assigning value to a global variable. It just doesn't work. I  have to mention that I don't know javascript nor jQuery I am making all this up from knowing other languages and reading docs.

Comment: @KiraArik I think that you should ask another question, remember to include your code.